# Recuperar Formulario Cerrado

Tags: c#, windows-forms

actualmente trabajo en un proyecto de C# con windows Form, a grandes rasgos obtengo datos desde un puerto en serie y los agrego a un ListBox en tiempo real. Este mismo ListBox originalmente estaba en la interfaz principal, pero por cuestiones de diseño se pasó a otra interfaz, para poder acceder a esta interfaz desde cualquier otro método declaro a la misma de manera global

```
   //Instancia de la interfaz Consola en el codigo de la interfaz principal
   ConsolaIUS consolaFIB = new ConsolaIUS();
```

Posterior hago uso de un objeto de interfaz en otra función pasando como parámetro el nombre del ListBox de la segunda interfaz.

```
      Boolean actualizacionC = controlador.ExeActualizacionDispositivo(idSeleccionado, HexIni, SecuanciaInicial, HexFin, SecuenciaFinal, arrFrames, pb_progresoUpdate, pb_progresoUpdate2, ModoManufactura, consolaFIB.lb_consola, RadioSelected, PRActualizarMT_1, th_hilo, btn_Iniciar, lb_paqueteActual, false);
```

Donde

```
    consolaFIB.lb_consola
```

Es el parametro del Nombre de ListBox en la interfaz secundaria, despues tengo un boton que invoca a la segunda interfaz

```
   consolaFIB.Show();
```

Y la primera vez que se oprime el botón, se muestra la segunda interfaz, cierro la segunda interfaz con el botón "X" de la ventana para probar la funcionalidad y la re intento abrir la segunda interfaz con el botón y falla enviando el siguiente Error:

```
 Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ObjectDisposedException' en System.Windows.Forms.dll
 Información adicional: No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado.
```

Comprendo que al cerra la segunda interfaz mi objeto se pierde.
La pregunta es ¿Existe alguna manera de recuperar el objeto y se siga viendo los datos en tiempo real?

Comment: Como lo cerras?

Comment: A través del Boton "X" en el encabezado de la segunda interfaz

Comment: no recuerdo el codigo.. si puedo despues te lo agrego... pero lo que tenes que hacer es cancelar el cierre (en el evento closing) y luego esconder el formulario...

Comment: Lo que esta nombrando como "Interfaz" es un formulario de windows forms? Es decir la clase que se llama ConsolaIUS hereda de System.Windows.Forms.Form ? Cuando menciona que "intento abrir la segunda interfaz con el botón y falla enviando el siguiente Error:" ese "intento" con que sentencias lo hace (publicar codigo)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando cierras el formulario, la instancia referenciada en la variable `consolaFIB` es descartada (Dispose) y por eso se produce el error que mencionas en la pregunta.

Una forma de lograr el funcionamiento esperado es impedir el cierre del formulario en el evento `FormClosing` con un código similar al siguiente:

```
private void consolaFIB_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Con esta instrucción cancelas el cierre del formulario
    e.Cancel = true;
    
    //Con esta instrucción ocultas el formulario
    this.Hide();            
}
```

Recuerda que debes [suscribirte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events) al evento.